# Parsing MSSQL datetime using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am retrieving date/time value from mssql database which looks like this:

```
2020-08-20T21:42:42.620Z
```

If I do:

```
moment("2020-08-20T21:42:42.620Z").calendar()
```

I get the result:

> "Yesterday at 5:42 PM"

Instead of 9:42 PM.

I tried to setup the format using:

```
moment("2020-08-20T21:42:42.620Z",'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.0Z').calendar()
```

but I still get :

> "Yesterday at 5:42 PM"

Has anyone been able to parse date/time format uisng moment?

Comment: The assumption would be that moment is converting the date to your timezone.  Is your timezone `GMT-4`?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/

Comment: @Taplar how can it covert to utc by default? I thought it uses the local timezone by default unless utc() method is used

Answer (score 0):

By default it shows local time ,you need to parse it in utc so use this

```
moment.utc("2020-08-20T21:42:42.620Z", 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.0Z').calendar()
```